# Help needed in understanding the basics of Cartan decomposition of a Lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to learn the basics of Cartan decomposition of Lie algebra, and have come across the following example.

Consider $\mathfrak{gl_n}$ as the Lie algebra of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let the Cartan involution on $\mathfrak{gl_n}$ be given by 
$\theta (A)=-A^*, $ where $*$ denotes conjugate transpose of $A \in \mathfrak{gl_n}$ and the  killing form is given by  $$(X,Y)=-\frac{1}{2} Tr(A\theta(B)).$$ 
I have the following questions:

$1)$ What does it mean by $\pm1-$eigenspace of $\theta$ ? This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition#Cartan_pairs) tells that

> Since $\theta ^ 2 =1,$ the linear map $\theta$ has the two eigenvalues $\pm1.$

What is the definition of eigen-space in this context? I know eigenspaces only in the context of basic linear algebra. I got confused here.

$2)$ What is the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ ? Any suggestions for references?

Thanks!

Comment: $\theta$ acts on matrices. IOW $\theta$ is a mapping from $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ to itself. So its eigenspaces are subspaces of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. For example $\theta(I_n)=-I_n$, so $I_n$ is an eigenvector belonging to eigenvalue $-1$. As are all the real diagonal matrices.

Comment: The [Cartan decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition) refers to a decomposition of a *semisimple* Lie algebra. For question 2.) start therefore with $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$.

Comment: Ok! Is it true that the decomposition $\mathfrak{gl}_n = u_n \oplus \mathcal{H}_n$ is orthogonal? Here $\mathfrak{u}_n$ is space of skew-hermitian matrices and $\mathcal{H}_n$ is space of Hermitian matrices. I have been told to prove this. But it does not seem to be the case. Could you look into this if the decomposition is orthogonal? If so how can I prove it? I asked a question here: (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079372/how-to-show-trace-of-ab-is-zero-for-a-in-mathfraku-n-and-b-in-mathcal) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\theta$ is a linear map of the vector space $\mathfrak{gl}_n$.  Eigenvectors of $\theta$ are matrices $X$ such that $-X^* = \lambda X$.  Since $\theta^2$ is the identity function, eigenvalues of $\theta$ must be square roots of $1$, namely $\pm 1$.

The eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is the set
$$
\left\{X \in \mathfrak{gl_n} : -X^* =X\right\}
$$
This is the set of skew-hermitian matrices.
The $-1$-eigenspace is the set
$$
\left\{X \in \mathfrak{gl_n} : X^* =X\right\}
$$
of hermitian matrices.

Look in Helgason's book *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces* for more.