# If $A$ is Hermitian and $B$ is skew-hermitian matrix, then trace of $AB$ is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I reduced a problem to showing that if $A \in End (\mathbb{C}^n)$ is such that $A=-\bar{A}^t$ and if $B\in End (\mathbb{C}^n)$ such that $B=\bar{B}^t$ then the trace $Tr(AB)=0$.

But I cannot show this. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample: $$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}i&7\\-7&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\2&3\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}14+i&21+2i\\-7&-14\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: Okay. Perhaps I didn't phrase my question properly. If you don't mind, could you have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079221/help-needed-in-understanding-the-basics-of-cartan-decomposition-of-a-lie-algebra This problem came out of my attempt to show that the decomposition $\mathfrak{gl}_n = u_n \oplus \mathcal{H}_n$ is orthogonal. Here $\mathfrak{u}_n$ denotes space of skew-symmetric matrices and $\mathcal{H}_n$ denotes space of Hermitian matrices. I wanted to say that the decomposition is orthogonal if $(A,B)$ was zero. Could you help?

Comment: In my above comment, $A \in \mathfrak{u}_n$ and $B \in \mathcal{H}_n$.

Comment: @math, I'm not sure I understand; perhaps you could close this question and ask another.

Comment: Hmm, +1, but I think $A=iI_n$ and $B=I_n$ is a much simpler counterexample ...

Comment: @vadim123 No problem! I will ask another.