# How to show trace of $AB$ is zero for $A \in \mathfrak{u}_n$ and $B \in \mathcal{H}_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Please have a look at this question: [Help needed in understanding the basics of Cartan decomposition of a Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079221/help-needed-in-understanding-the-basics-of-cartan-decomposition-of-a-lie-algebra)

I want to show that the decomposition $\mathfrak{gl}_n = u_n \oplus \mathcal{H}_n$ is orthogonal. Here $\mathfrak{u}_n$ denotes space of skew-hermitian matrices and $\mathcal{H}_n$ denotes space of Hermitian matrices. I wanted to say that the decomposition is orthogonal if $(A,B)$ is zero where $A \in \mathfrak{u}_n$ and $B \in \mathcal{H}_n$.

I am stuck at basically the definition $$(A,B)= -\frac{1}{2} Tr(A \theta (B))=\frac{1}{2} Tr(A B^*).$$  I don't know how to show that last expression is zero. Please help!

Comment: By skew-symmetric you mean skew-hermitian?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I will edit!

Comment: I think this might work if you only consider real matrices.  However, over the complex matrices, we have situations like $iI \in u_n$ and $I \in H_n$.

Comment: Let me try ... ${tr(AB^*)}={tr(AB^*)^t}=\overline{tr((AB^*)^*)}=-\overline{tr(B^*A)}=-\overline{tr(AB^*)}$ ... nope can't get it right... just shows that ${tr(AB^*)}$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: If $A \in u_n, B \in H_n$, you can show that $Tr(AB) = \alpha i$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, but not more, as @Omnomnomnom's example shows.

Comment: In any case, I want to show that decomposition is orthogonal. What's the standard way for this?

Comment: Well, apparently this is not the case.  Are your sure that this involution is a Cartan involution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for $\theta(A) = -A^T$, defined over $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb R)$.  Note that if $A$ is skew-symmetric and $B$ is symmetric and both $A$ and $B$ have real entries, then
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB^*) = 0
$$
as desired.

---

In order for $\theta(A) = -A^*$ to be a Cartan involution, we need to show that 
$B_\theta(X,Y) = -B(X,\theta(Y))$
defines a positive definite bilinear form (where $B$ denotes the [killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form)).

In this case, we have
$$
B_\theta(X,Y) = 
-B(X,-Y^*) = -\operatorname{trace}([X,[-Y^*,\cdot]])
$$
If this map on the pair $X,Y$ is positive definite with respect to the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ (as you've defined it), then $\theta$ qualifies as a Cartan involution.  I suspect that this is not the case.

---

It suffices to check whether this is the case for $X,Y$ in a basis.  Take $X = E_{ij} = e_ie_j^*$ and $Y = E_{pq} = e_pe_q^*$.

For a matrix $A$, we have
$$
[-Y^*,A] = -e_q(e_p^* A) + (A e_q)e_p^*
$$
This can be written out very nicely with some matrix formatting that I don't care to do.  Now, we have
$$
[X,[-Y^*,A]] = \\
e_ie_j^*(-e_q(e_p^* A) + (A e_q)e_p^*) - (-e_q(e_p^* A) + (A e_q)e_p^*)e_ie_j^* = \\
-\delta_{jq}\cdot e_i(e_p^*A) + (e_j^* A e_q) \cdot e_ie_p^*
+ (e_p^* A e_i)\cdot e_q e_j^* - \delta_{pi}\cdot (A e_q)e_j^*
$$
The map $A \mapsto [X,[-Y^*,A]]$ is a linear map on $A$ whose trace we must compute.  So, if  the above has negative trace regardless for all choices $i,j,p,q,$ then $\theta$ is a Cartan involution.

Comment: I didn't understand which map should be positive definite. Did you mean the Hermitian structure $(.,.)$ on $\mathfrak{gl}_n$? If so, it is positive definite.

Comment: I don't get why should we do this complicated computation. We can simply compute $(A,A)=\frac{1}{2} \sum _ {i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2$ where $\lambda_i$ are diagonal entries of $A \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$. Thus, it is positive definite. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: The question is whether $B_\theta$ defines a positive definite form

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia page claims that $\theta(X) = -X^T$ is a Cartan involution on $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb R)$.  It does not claim that there is any analogous involution on, for example, $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)$.  Perhaps there is no such involution.

Comment: Ok! In my homework as well, there is no mention of Cartan involution. Below is a sequence of questions in my HW: 1) Show that the Hermitian structure is positive definite and that $\theta$ is an anti-unitary Lie algebra involution (i.e. $\theta^2 = Id$ ?), which I did. 2) Show that $+1$ eigenspace $u_n$ is Lie algebra of unitary group and $-1$ eigenspace $\mathcal{H}_n$ is space of Hermitian matrices. I have more or less done this. 3) Show that decomposition is orthogonal. There is no mention of Cartan decomposition or anything.

Comment: Are you sure that they are referring to the complex matrices?  Check the notation.

Comment: absolutely sure! :)

Comment: Well, we've demonstrated several times now that the decomposition is not orthogonal, if this is your definition of orthogonal. Maybe we're using the wrong inner product?  Maybe you should make a new post dedicated directly to your homework question.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. Are you aware of other definition of orthogonal decomposition (like in my case)?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what your question is asking for at this point.  It seems wrong to me.  However, perhaps a better mathematician than I can spot the method to the madness.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help!